# Stacked Bar Chart (AmCharts 4) with one series and repeating category

Tags: javascript, c#, amcharts

I'm currently creating a chart whose data is dynamically fetch from a database. Based on this data, I want to create a Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart that has only one series. Would that be possible in AmCharts? Or do I need a different approach?

Here's what I'd like as final result:
[image]

Here's a sample of what I'm currently doing: [Chart Sample](https://codepen.io/sprukutoytoy/pen/jOKPqjd)

I'm also aware that using `series.stacked = true;` would make a column chart stacked but I think this needs to have multiple series which I want to avoid for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<style></style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>


<body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px;height: 200px;background:#c7cacb;margin: 0 auto;"></div>
  <script>

    am5.ready(function () {

      var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
      root._logo.dispose();

      root.setThemes([
        am5themes_Animated.new(root)
      ]);

      var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: false,
        wheelY: false,
        layout: root.verticalLayout
      }));


      var data = [{
        "year": "Payments",
        "europe": 50,
        "namerica": 0,
        "asia": 0,
      }, {
        "year": "Invoiced",
        "europe": 30,
        "namerica": 0,
        "asia": 0,
      }, {
        "year": "Other Adjustment Sum",
        "europe": 40,
        "namerica": 20,
        "asia": 39,
      }]

      var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        categoryField: "year",
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
      }));

      yAxis.data.setAll(data);

      var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        min: 0,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
      }));

      xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
        am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
          min: 0,
          numberFormat: "''",
          renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            minGridDistance: 60
          }),
        })
      );

      let myRange = [
        {
          x: 20,
        },
        {
          x: 40,
        },
        {
          x: 60,
        },
        {
          x: 80,
        },
        {
          x: 100,
        },
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length + 2; i++) {
        let value = myRange[i].x;

        let rangeDataItem = xAxis.makeDataItem({
          value: value,
        });

        let range = xAxis.createAxisRange(rangeDataItem);

        rangeDataItem.get('label').setAll({
          forceHidden: false,
          text: value,
        });
      }


      var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
        centerX: am5.p50,
        x: am5.p50
      }));

      function makeSeries(name, fieldName, color) {
        var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
          name: name,
          stacked: true,
          xAxis: xAxis,
          yAxis: yAxis,
          baseAxis: yAxis,
          fill: color,
          valueXField: fieldName,
          categoryYField: "year"
        }));

        series.columns.template.setAll({
          tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryY}: {valueX}",
          tooltipY: am5.percent(90)
        });
        series.data.setAll(data);

        series.appear();

      }

      makeSeries("Europe", "europe", "#83cdf4");
      makeSeries("North America", "namerica","#caa3ed");
      makeSeries("Asia", "asia","#eec48b");

      chart.appear(1000, 100);
    }); 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll look into it since I'm not really familiar yet on AmCharts5. What this answer lacks for me is that, the data format was changed, which is not an option for me. I'm stuck with the current data structure which is in the example.